# Allowing only certain servers/websites connect to script

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have a JavaScript script, which I want to sell to my clients. The problem is there are no on site changes required for the script to work so they can simply link to the script and get the benefits - it's an auto tagging and conversion setup type script for Analytics which has had a lot of work go into it.

Is there a way to only allow the websites see the script? So if a human went there it would be 403. I tried using htaccess and allowing access from the server IP, which of course didn't work...

Comment: Neither a "website" nor a "human" ever downloads the script, it's always a computer. Whether that computer then executes the script or displays it to a user or both is non of your business. In other words, if you make that script publicly downloadable, humans can see it; no way around it.

Comment: @deceze in a DAC security model, sure, but there are situations where you want to limit the operation to execution hehe :)

Comment: @MonkeyFace there are ways to obfuscate a script and limit its use using keys of some sort, although it's a pain. IMHO if you share your code with your customers, i think you will find that people will pay you for use; especially if they like what it does. Supporting original authors of code is quite common.  If it's so valuable that you must keep it hidden then the problem is non trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to differenciate if the code is requested by a page it is embedded in or outside of it, right?

The only setting you may can rely on is the http-header "Referer". This way you can also limit your script to only be included in documents on the domain *www.example1.com*, but not on *www.example2.com*.

Here's a request for the GoogleAnalytics script on this page:

```
GET /ga.js HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687926/allowing-only-certain-servers-websites-connect-to-script
Connection: keep-alive
```

But if someone knows how your "security-check" works, he can easily view the js-code via Firebug or another developer-tool, or just create the request using another tool. So, this is not secure at all, but does, if at all, just prevent some people, who just tried to get the script within 2sec. Everyone trying harder will get to it.

What you can do as well, is to do some Obfuscation ... make the code as hard to read as possible :)
Here's a link to another question where they talk about malware using this technique to hide what it's really doing: https://superuser.com/questions/418121/what-is-javascript-obfuscation-and-why-is-it-a-threat

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you could host the script? If so you can issue an access/API key to clients and serve this via a key authentication check from a simple web app.

Otherwise you could share a secret with the client and incorporate a key check into the script. [I've written a gist demonstrating javascript bitwise encoding](https://gist.github.com/steventux/2024426), the 'salt' argument should be your shared secret. You should also compress/obfuscate the script.

It's worth mentioning that the latter suggestion isn't totally secure, it's a trade-off on how much a single copy of the script is worth to you and what the effort to secure it will cost you.